# Importing MakeFile as MingW Project

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

I have a MingW exported MakeFile ,which compiles great. The MingW project file (.mdsp) wasn't committed in cvs at all. Is there a way i can import the MakeFile as MingW Project or .mdsp generatore from MakeFile ?
I wanted to use MingW in linux, because of the IDE's i came around, this seems to so light weight ...

Comment: When you refer WinGW, perhaps you refer not the [compiler](http://www.mingw.org/), but some IDE ([MinGW Developer Studio](http://koti.mbnet.fi/vaultec/mingwstudio.php)?). You cannot use MinGW on Linux, because MinGW is GCC ported compiler for *Windows*.

Comment: @dma_k: Well, you can use it on Linux for cross-compiling.

Comment: I see what you mean: mingw binaries for Linux will generate Win32 object files... Is that what you need? But IDE will not run on Linux, right?

Comment: As erik said, i can use it for Cross Compilation, i didn't mean to Compile or debug in MingW Studio, all i need is an IDE for my Project, where i can search inside my Project, view all files ... finally export make file and compile in command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no easy way importing a Makefile to MingW. We have to create a new Project in MingW and then have to manually add files and set include directories in .mdsp file. I used a Shell Script for that, which has some issues. Once i fix it, i'll Post it here.